# Issue with np.vstack

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn

I have split my data into training and test, followed by the split of training into another train set and a validation set. To this new train set and validation set I have applied the below transformation. I am implementing a Random forest regression, so at the next step I apply the transformations to these set and try to combine it into one. The issue is np.vstack isn't returning me the correct shape:
Output:
(2, 1) <- should have been (25455, 2394)
(21636, 2394)
(3819, 2394)

Could someone one tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
Xtrain_rf, Xtest_rf = train_test_split(insurance_data_prep, test_size=0.15, random_state=42)
Xtrain2_rf, Xval_rf = train_test_split(Xtrain_rf, test_size=0.15, random_state=42)

full_transform_rf = ColumnTransformer([
    ("num", StandardScaler(), attributes_num),
    ("cat", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), attributes_cat),
])

## fit transform in the train set
Xtrain2_rf_att_prepared = full_transform_rf.fit_transform(Xtrain2_rf_att)
## transform in the validation set
Xval_rf_att_prepared = full_transform_rf.transform(Xval_rf_att)

whole_train_set_attributes_rf = np.vstack((Xtrain2_rf_att_prepared, Xval_rf_att_prepared))
print(whole_train_set_attributes_rf.shape)
print(Xtrain2_rf_att_prepared.shape)
print(Xval_rf_att_prepared.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your code with a dataset of my own, and one problem I have ran into is that `Xtrain2_rf_att` and `Xval_rf_att` variables have not been defined in your code snippet. Those are the variables that you passed to your `ColumnTransformer`.

I guess that in your case the variables are defined but what you really want to pass to the `ColumnTransformer` are `Xtrain2_rf` and `Xval_rf`.

If this does not solve your problem, could you edit your question and add the following information?:

- `insurance_data_prep` shape and columns (or some of them)
- `attributes_num` and `attributes_dat`
- clearly provide the outputs from the three prints statements at the end of your code and not just one of them

You might need to use a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to replace your dataframe, we will see